# How to run a PHP file to a server created by firebase

Tags: php, firebase, server, webhooks

I have to test my webhook response. So i create a server using firebase. but don't know how to run a php file inside that server to check my webhook response. Anyone knows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't understand what firebase is, based on your question.  Firebase is not a VM that hosts server side code written in a server side language like php.  It is a "Platform as a service" system that lets you piece together the server using their components.

In short firebase is used in place of a server with server side code.  It doesn't seem appropriate to test a web hook you have on a server.

You should just be able to use curl, or a [REST testing tool like Postman](https://www.getpostman.com) or any of a gazillion different web testing tools for this.

For PHP specifically [here are is a very up to date article on php based web testing tools](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/automated-php-test/).